# Shopping cart for anonymous users and it's protection

Tags: shopping-cart

If my shopping cart is stored in a DB for both anonymous and registred users, what is the best way to protect it from an attack? I found a lot of discussions about where to store shopping carts but nothing about this matter.

What if some bot just doesn't store cookies and sends requests to the shopping cart over and over again. Without cookies it's different anonymous user every time thus database will grow.

Should I check the ip address and redirect to a captcha? But real users may have same ip addresses, so the algorithm should be more complicated to not disturb them.

Any ideas or links?

Answer (score 1):

Captcha's are a pretty popular way to go. I'm guessing most people (like me) rather dislike them and generally can't read them, but they're generally probably pretty easy to implement and more efficient than most alternatives.

The less effort approach to checking IPs is having all anonymous users require a Captcha.

I would also suggest having a time-out (based on activity) of no more than a few hours on carts of anonymous users (after which you can probably delete it).

You'd also want an upper limit on the number of items, and, if this number is high, also possibly prevent (though Captcha?) users from adding too many items to their cart in inhumanly short succession.